# How can I attach a libGDX actor to a box2D body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm creating game like hill climb racing.

I created my car with the help of shapes and joints but I don't know how to attach graphics to it. I used actors and sprites before for the sake of learning, but I don't know how to use those with box2d bodies.

How can I?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen two ways of achieving this, one is to let the **UserData** of the **Box2D** `Body` hold the `Sprite`.

```
body.setUserData(mySprite);
```

And in the update you retrieve that and apply position and rotation to the `Sprite` according to the `Body`'s transform;

```
Sprite sprite = (Sprite)body.getUserData();
Vector2 position = body.getPosition();
// Center body is center sprite here
float hw = sprite.getWidth() / 2.0f;
float hh = sprite.getHeight() / 2.0f;
float a = body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
float x = position.x - hw;
float y = position.y - hh;

sprite.setPosition(x, y);
sprite.setRotation(a);
```

The other approach is to keep track of an object that is the amalgamation of the `Sprite` and the `Body`;

```
public class MyGameObject {
  private Body body;
  private Sprite sprite;

  public void update() {
    Vector2 position = body.getPosition();
    // Center body is center sprite here
    float hw = sprite.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    float hh = sprite.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    float a = body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
    float x = position.x - hw;
    float y = position.y - hh;

    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    sprite.setRotation(a);
  }
}
```

I think it's largely a matter of preference, I prefer the **UserData** approach myself as I need to "manually" keep track of less things that way.

Comment: well, actually, the best way would be to use *both* methods - use composition class (like in solution 2), and then set the userData to the composite object... that way you get a) easy access to data from physics routines, b) have the cleanest abstraction via proper composition pattern, c) can easily introduce custom logic to the object. That's exactly why most (if not all) game frameworks have some kind of `entity` class, that serves as a "junction point" for all of the game entity functionalities (visual, physical, AI-related etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setUserData method to attach an Object to the box2D body (like for example a Sprite or an Actor):

```
body.setUserData(sprite);
```

Accordingly you can get your Sprite back like this:

```
(Sprite) body.getUserData();
```

Note that you need to cast to Sprite.